# Why does my Access database object variable lose connection to its source file midway through reading its Modules container?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

We use a VBA tool to extract modules, forms and reports from our Access applications and create an executable for users.  This tool has been working without any problems until very recently. However, when I use it to extract from a couple of applications, I keep on encountering an "Automation Error (The remote procedure call failed)" error.  However, my colleague (running the same code on a virtually identical build) is able to run it ok.

This is running on Win10 Pro (v2004 - 19041.685), Office 2016 Pro Plus (16.0.4266.1001).  I believe my colleague's machine should be the same, as we have only just moved across to these laptops.

This is the core code:

```
Public Sub ExportAll()

    On Error GoTo ErrorProc
    Dim oAccessApp As Access.Application
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim oDb As Database
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    strFile = "accdb path"
    strFolder = oApp.GetFolder(strFile)
    Set oAccessApp = oApp.OpenDatabase(strFile)
    Set oDb = oAccessApp.CurrentDb
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists((strFolder) & "\SCC") Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder & "\SCC"
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(strFolder & "\SCC\Modules") Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder & "\SCC\Modules"
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(strFolder & "\SCC\Forms") Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder & "\SCC\Forms"
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(strFolder & "\SCC\Reports") Then
        fso.CreateFolder strFolder & "\SCC\Reports"
    End If
        
    For Each oDoc In oDb.Containers("Modules").Documents
        DoEvents
        sFilePath = strFolder & "\SCC\Modules\" & oDoc.Name & ".bas.txt"
        oAccessApp.SaveAsText acModule, oDoc.Name, sFilePath
    Next
    
    For Each oDoc In oDb.Containers("Forms").Documents
        DoEvents
        sFilePath = strFolder & "\SCC\Forms\" & oDoc.Name & ".frm.txt"
        oAccessApp.SaveAsText acForm, oDoc.Name, sFilePath
    Next
    
    For Each oDoc In oDb.Containers("Reports").Documents
        DoEvents
        sFilePath = strFolder & "\SCC\Reports\" & oDoc.Name & ".rpt.txt"
        oAccessApp.SaveAsText acReport, oDoc.Name, sFilePath
    Next
    
    oDb.Close
    Set oDb = Nothing
    oAccessApp.Quit
    Set oAccessApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorProc:
    If Not (oAccessApp Is Nothing) Then
        oAccessApp.Quit
    End If
    Set oAccessApp = Nothing
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error " & Err.Number
End Sub
```

As the extraction takes place, the database being extracted should remain open throughout. Each failure occurs in the `For Each oDoc In oDb.Containers("Modules").Documents` loop, and happens when a particular module is referenced by the oDoc variable.  When I step through and reach the offending module, all is fine until the line with `oDoc.Name` is hit, at which point the database closes and all the messages for the object oDb reads "".

The module causing the problem is below:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'
' Opens file using default program
'  (.xls files open in Excel, .doc files open in Word, etc)
'


'Code Courtesy of
'Dev Ashish

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
        ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long
#End If


Public Enum ShellExecuteWinStyle
    WIN_NORMAL = 1         'Open Normal
    WIN_MAX = 2            'Open Maximized
    WIN_MIN = 3            'Open Minimized
End Enum


Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS = 32&
Private Const ERROR_NO_ASSOC = 31&
Private Const ERROR_OUT_OF_MEM = 0&
Private Const ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2&
Private Const ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND = 3&
Private Const ERROR_BAD_FORMAT = 11&

'
' Opens file using default program
'  (.xls files open in Excel, .doc files open in Word, etc)
'
Function ShellExecute(strFile As Variant, lShowHow As ShellExecuteWinStyle)
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lRet As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lRet As Long
    #End If
        
    Dim varTaskID As Variant
    Dim stRet As String
    Dim stFile As String

    If IsNull(strFile) Or strFile = "" Then Exit Function
    
    stFile = strFile
    
    'First try ShellExecute
    lRet = apiShellExecute(hWndAccessApp, vbNullString, _
            stFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, lShowHow)
            
    If lRet > ERROR_SUCCESS Then
        stRet = vbNullString
        lRet = -1
    Else
        Select Case lRet
            Case ERROR_NO_ASSOC:
                'Try the OpenWith dialog
                varTaskID = Shell("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL " _
                        & stFile, WIN_NORMAL)
                lRet = (varTaskID <> 0)
            Case ERROR_OUT_OF_MEM:
                stRet = "Error: Out of Memory/Resources. Couldn't Execute!"
            Case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
                stRet = "Error: File not found.  Couldn't Execute!"
            Case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
                stRet = "Error: Path not found. Couldn't Execute!"
            Case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT:
                stRet = "Error:  Bad File Format. Couldn't Execute!"
            Case Else:
        End Select
    End If
    ShellExecute = lRet & _
                IIf(stRet = "", vbNullString, ", " & stRet)
End Function
```

I have tried the following:

- removing the problem module (process completes successfully)
- renaming the module
- removing pro-compile conditional statements
- moving extraction code to a new database
- extracting from database with only problem module plus module with comments
- repair MS Office
- reinstall MS Office
- downgrade Windows updates

Does anyone have any idea why this might be failing?  Any suggestions on how to rectify would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try saving the module through the VBE, and inspecting it for any curious properties. If none are found, re-import and see if the problem keeps occurring. There are several properties that are not visible in the VBE but are stored with the code in these modules. Also, `Application.SaveAsText` tends to save a text file in the same location as the database when hitting an error containing the error description, check if any are present.

Comment: I've just tried Exporting and Importing both modules (extraction and Windows API call).  In each case, the only property appearing is the VB_Name attribute, showing the module name.

Unfortunately, the process isn't failing on `Application.SaveAsText` so there is no text file to review. If fails when the code tries to access the particular item in the Documents collection of the Modules container.